# Error when calling datetime.date()

Tags: python, date, time

I have two versions, both which don't work for a reason I can't tell.

First Version

```
from datetime import datetime, date

d = datetime.date(2011, 01, 01)
print(d)
```

Which gives

```
  File "timeSince.py", line 3
    d = datetime.date(2011, 01, 01)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Second Version

```
from datetime import datetime, date

d = datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
print(d)
```

Which gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeSince.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received
a 'int'
```

Running Python 3.3

Answer (score 3):

You imported date from datetime, so this will work:

```
>>> d = date(2011, 1, 1)
>>> d
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

no need to put the `datetime` infront

when you import a method from a module, you no longer use the name of the module to call that method because you imported that specific method!

**note:**

Your first instance is invalid syntax because you can't have a 0 in the beginning of an integer in python. You must use it this way: `date(2011, 1, 1)` and not this way: `date(2011, 01, 01)`

Comment: Still gives the same error.

   File "timeSince.py", line 3
  d = date(2011, 01, 01)
      ^
 SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: you can't use the integers starting with a 0 in python! it doesn't work! This works when you actually use correct python syntax!

Answer (score 2):

You are using integer literals with leading `0` digits, which are not allowed in Python 3.

In Python 2, these were interpreted as octal values:

```
>>> 017
15
```

but the syntax is ambiguous and confusing to those not coming from a C background, and only the `0o123` syntax with leading `0o` is now supported. The old syntax was made a syntax error to prevent people that *do* know the C octal syntax from creating subtle bugs.

Both versions try to use the `datetime.date()` method without an instance. You want to use just `date()` instead:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> date(2011, 1, 1)
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
>>> datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> datetime.date
<method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>
```

Comment: My second version in the post is not.

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement is wrong (or at least not helpful), so you end up using a date method on the datetime class (which converts datetimes to dates) rather than the date class (which creates dates).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> datetime.date
<method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>
>>> datetime.date.__doc__
'Return date object with same year, month and day.'
```

Do this instead:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2011,1,1)
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
>>> datetime.date.__doc__
'date(year, month, day) --> date object'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two separate problems. You can't write integers with leading `0`s (which is why your first version fails), and you've imported `date` from the `datetime` module already, so you shouldn't be trying to re-reference it (which is why your second version fails). Your code should look like this:

```
from datetime import date
d = date(2011, 1, 1)
print(d) # prints "2011-01-01"
```